# Repeat sequence in panel data

Tags: sequence, stata, repeat, panel-data

I am working with panel data on labour productivity from 1970 to 2005 and defined it as `xtset sector year`. As I'm looking for average annual productivity growth with fixed weights in a base year, I am trying to copy the weights (`nominalshare`) of 1970 to all other years. Note that the sequence is quite important, as different sectors have different values.

My code is the following:

```
egen totalva = sum(VA), by(year)
by sector: gen nominalshare = VA/totalva if year == 1970
```

Manually copying the weights is not an option, as I have observations of 35 years and I'm researching different base years.

So I am trying to copy my exact results for 1970 to all following years. Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Note that `by sector:` is superfluous. The calculation is not affected by which `sector` an observation is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that functions under the `egen` command typically ignore missing values:

```
egen totalva = total(VA), by(year)
gen temp = VA/totalva if year == 1970

by sector: egen nominalshare = mean(temp)
drop temp
```

Note also the scope for using the `cond()` function:

```
egen totalva = total(VA), by(year)
gen temp = cond(year == 1970, VA/totalva, 0)

by sector: egen nominalshare = max(temp)
drop temp
```

If using a `do` file, you could also use the `tempvar` command which would remove the need for the `drop temp` line.

Note: This version benefits from comments by @ander2ed.

Comment: `by sector : egen nominalshare = mean(temp)` will work with negatives

Comment: @ander2ed Not sure that will produce (what I believe to be) the correct value, which is the value of  total 1970 ratio (VA/totalval) for each sector populated to every subsequent year. I'm pretty sure `egen nominalshare = mean(temp)` will take a mean of this ratio in and a bunch of 0s for each sector to create a much smaller value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. 
Edit: I used Imo's solution as I don't have any negative VA/totalva values.

Comment: In your example, yes because you `gen temp = 0` first. Using OPs original `by sector : gen nominalshare` to create the `temp` variable first you will have missing values. Which will then be ignored by `mean()`

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the edits in 1 and 2. I was sloppy. However, I was correct in the use of the term function versus command as you use the function I was thinking of in your code below: `cond()`. Thanks once again for presenting such clear code and descriptions.

Comment: I only intended my comment to mean that using the `cond()` function would collapse the `gen` and `replace` commands in my intial codeblock into a single `gen` command.

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: I've made some further edits. Future readers do not need to know about details that aren't important or solutions you improved on. Feel free to reverse these if you don't like them, but your answer benefits from conciseness. (Earlier, I thought that "temp variable" was just your way of saying temporary variable, which naturally has a precise meaning in Stata, but you literally meant the variable `temp`; hence my misunderstanding.)

Comment: Thanks for the edits @ Nick Cox. I'll aim at concise responses in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer by @lmo and comments by @ander2ed focusing on `egen`, but here is another way, offering various two-line solutions, all thus shorter.

Note in passing that while `egen`'s `sum()` function works fine, it has been undocumented since Stata 9: there is now an equivalent `total()` function. This was done to make clearer the difference from the Stata function `sum()`, which produces cumulative or running sums.

Data, even fake data, help. On Statalist, people are asked to use `dataex` (SSC) to list example data, and that would be a good idea too here on Stack Overflow. Here are some silly data, as I don't have the OP's dataset to extract from:

```
clear 
input sector year va 
1  1970 40  
1  1971 70 
2  1970 60 
2  1971 30 
end
```

On the problem: instead of getting a total and dividing by it to get proportional shares, we can go straight there.

```
egen pcva = pc(va), by(year) prop
```

We can spread the 1970 values to all other years this way:

```
egen pcva1970 = total(pcva * (year == 1970)), by(sector) 

list, sepby(sector) 

     +--------------------------------------+
     | sector   year   va   pcva   pcva1970 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |      1   1970   40     .4         .4 |
  2. |      1   1971   70     .7         .4 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  3. |      2   1970   60     .6         .6 |
  4. |      2   1971   30     .3         .6 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

`total()` can feed on an expression, not just a variable name, and the expression is `pcva * (year == 1970)`. The true or false comparison `year == 1970` yields 1 if and only if `year` is `1970` and 0 otherwise. The effect is to produce a total that is just the selected value and it is placed in every pertinent observation.

Here are two other ways of ignoring everything but the 1970 values:

```
egen pcva1970 = total(pcva / (year == 1970)), by(sector) 
egen pcva1970 = total(cond(year == 1970, pcva, .)), by(sector)
```

As with the answer by @lmo, these solutions both hinge on Stata's ignoring missings for most (not all!) purposes.

There is a review of such technique at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055

NOTE In this particular example, 1970 is the first year, so this is another solution:

```
egen pcva = pc(va), by(year) prop 
bysort sector (year) : gen pcva1970 = pcva[1]
```